# How to display data in between header and footer only

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table

I have done a simple html page with a little CSS (not really good in CSS) to display the header and footer with data in between, but when I create a table data in between with long data it overlaps with the footer and the header on the following page. Below is the code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p { page-break-after: always; }
      .footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; }
      .header { position: fixed; top: 0px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="header">this is the header</div><br>

<!--     <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p> -->

    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <div class="footer">this is the footer</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is the output:

[image: overlapping picture]

But if I do it with a `<p>` CSS I think it works fine with this code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p { page-break-after: always; }
      .footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; }
      .header { position: fixed; top: 0px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="header">this is the header</div><br>

    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p>

    <div class="footer">this is the footer</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the output:

[image: looks good]

How can I display the table data before the footer and continues after the header of the next page?

Comment: Where does this output come from? PDF converter?

Comment: currently i hardcoded it, but later i'll call the data from the db using PHP. its to print report

Comment: no your css is broken, as the header floats on top of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering and printing are going to be a little different ...

Did you try the proper html5 tags?

```
 <header class="header">this is the header</header><br>

    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p>

    <footer class="footer">this is the footer</footer>
```

Comment: `<footer class="footer">...</div>`  :-p

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this was what you were asking, but the `fixed` position, is outside the normal flow of the page.  Meaning that it does not take up space.  So to offset that you can wrap you page in a div, and give it margins that match the size of the header and the footer.

This way that content doesn't get covered by the header.  It will still get covered by the footer if it has a scroll bar.  Typically you would only fix the header like this.

I also colored the background to make it easier to see, and I switched them from classes `.` to ids `#`.  These are main page elements and you should only have one, so they should be IDs.

Click the button to see what I mean.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
     $('#test').click(function(){
          if($('#page').css('margin-top') == '60px'){
               $('#page').css('margin-top', '');
          }else{
              $('#page').css('margin-top', '60px');
          }
     });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p {
          page-break-after: always;
        }
      #footer { 
        position: fixed; 
        bottom: 0px; 
        width:100%; 
        height:40px; 
        background: #eee; 
      }
      #header {
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0px; 
        width:100%; 
        height:60px; 
        background: #eee;
       }
      #page{ 
        /*margin-top: 60px; /* should match height of header */
        margin-bottom: 40px;/* should match height of footer */
        width:100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="header">this is the header</div><br>

<!--     <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p> -->
    <div id="page" >
          <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th> 
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Test" id="test" />Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    

    <div id="footer">this is the footer</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi i think it kinda work, but the data ends so close to the footer do you know how to set a margin or something so it views a bit higher than the footer?

Comment: yes but it's dinner, probably some default style from SO page is adding some padding and what not.

Comment: just change `margin-bottom: 40px;` in the css to something greater, maybe `60px`?

Answer (score 0):

Just `.footr` make its position `absolute` and set the `bottom` to negative length:
i.e :

```
.footer { position: absoulte; bottom: -10px; }
```

#### Update

You may also, set `.header` position to be absolute, but you will loss it as flying header.

```
.header { position: absolute; top: 0px; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p { page-break-after: always; }
      .footer { position: absoulte; bottom: -10px; }
      .header { position: absolute; top: 0px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="header">this is the header</div><br>

<!--     <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p><br>
    <p>lorem ipsum ...</p> -->

    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <div class="footer">this is the footer</div>

  </body>
</html>
```